# Class-scoped enum

Tags: c++, enums, static-members, boost-python

I have a c++ class with an enum inside, and I wanted to mimick that with `boost::python`, so that I can write `MyClass.value` in python. `boost::python::class_` does not have an `enum_` method, and I was looking for workarounds.

1. I first tried with lambdas like

   ```
   MyClass{
       enum{value1,value2};
   };

   class_<MyClass>("MyClass").add_property("value1",&[](){return value1;}).staticmethod("value1");
   ```

   which gives compiler error (in `get_signature` for `add_property`). I know I could create getter method for each of the values, but that seems very awkward to me (typing-wise).
2. Using `attr`:

   ```
   auto classObj=class_<MyClass>("MyClass");
   classObj.attr("value1")=(int)value1;
   classObj.attr("value2")=(int)value2;
   ```

   but it cannot be chained like `.def` and other methods returning reference to the instance.

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Outside of `MyClass` you would need to reference the enum values like `MyClass::value1`, though I am out of my element with boost-python stuff.

Comment: +1 for bothering to format this properly.

Answer (score 13):

You can do it using a scope:

```
#include <boost/python/module.hpp>
#include <boost/python/class.hpp>
#include <boost/python/scope.hpp>
#include <boost/python/enum.hpp>

namespace bp = boost::python;

class MyClass{
    public:
        enum MyEnum {value1,value2};
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(nestedtest){

    bp::scope the_scope
        = bp::class_<MyClass>("MyClass")
        ;

    bp::enum_<MyClass::MyEnum>("MyEnum")
        .value("value1", MyClass::value1)
        .value("value2", MyClass::value2)
        .export_values()
        ;
}
```

Then in python, your enum values are:

```
In [8]: nestedtest.MyClass.MyEnum.values
Out[8]: {0: nestedtest.MyEnum.value1, 1: nestedtest.MyEnum.value2}

In [9]: nestedtest.MyClass.MyEnum.value1
Out[9]: nestedtest.MyEnum.value1

In [10]: nestedtest.MyClass.MyEnum.value2
Out[10]: nestedtest.MyEnum.value2
```

(from my ipython shell, I tested this and all ;)

Comment: The enum is nested, which is not what I want; it is obnoxious and less readable to type `.MyEnum` without some added value.

Comment: The added value is that if, say, your enum values were all `ThingyA` `ThingyB` `ThingyC`, then you expose them to python as `Thingy.A` `Thingy.B` `Thingy.C`. As the sort of obnoxious person that campaigns against namespace pollution and the associated global namespace ozone hole and all that, I value this feature ;)

Comment: That's a matter of opinion (which I don't agree with), in any case the question asks for `MyClass.value`.

Comment: You can get the behaviour you want by adding the following line for each enum value (assuming the same code as above). This will inject a new symbol into the "right" scope with the value you want. the_scope.attr("value1") = MyClass::value1;