# boost python wrappers for nested classes - restoring global scope

Tags: c++, boost, scope, boost-python

In [the Boost Python documentation for "Header "](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/python/doc/v2/scope.html),
it is described how to expose the subclass of a class.

However, I could not find any documentation on how to do this for multiple classes.
See the code below, modelled on the code in the documentation. If I want to write code like

```
w = nested.Z.W()
z.g()
```

etc. it does not work, since apparently once the scope has been defined to be X, it does not return to the global scope.
So, for example Z now lives in the scope of X. How can I make it return to the global scope? The documentation says

> Constructing a scope object with an argument changes the associated
>   global Python object to the one held by the argument, until the
>   lifetime of the scope object ends, at which time the associated global
>   Python object reverts to what it was before the  scope object was
>   constructed.

More generally, this is problematic, since what happens to the objects I may define in the module following the construction of this scope object?Will they all end up in the scope of X?

One way to resolve this would be a mechanism to restore global scope. Does anyone know how to do this? Any other way of resolving this would also be fine.

```
#include <boost/python/module.hpp>
#include <boost/python/class.hpp>
#include <boost/python/scope.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;

struct X
{
  void f() {}
  struct Y { int g() { return 42; } };
};

struct Z
{
  void f() {}
  struct W { int g() { return 91; } };
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(nested)
{
  // add some constants to the current (module) scope
  scope().attr("yes") = 1;
  scope().attr("no") = 0;

  // Change the current scope
  scope outer
    = class_<X>("X")
    .def("f", &X::f)
    ;

  // Define a class Y in the current scope, X
   class_<X::Y>("Y")
     .def("g", &X::Y::g)
     ;

  // Change the current scope 
  // (this does not work as one would hope - W ends up inside Z, but Z is now in X.)
  scope outer2
    = class_<Z>("Z")
    .def("f", &Z::f)
    ;

  // Define a class Y in the current scope, X
   class_<Z::W>("W")
     .def("g", &Z::W::g)
     ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Entering and exiting scope is simply handled by the lifetime of the `scope` object (...another way to say that is: a scope ends when the corresponding `scope` object is destructed). In the example, if you enclose the "outer" `scope` within braces, "outer2" will be (back) in the module scope.

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(nested)
{
  // add some constants to the current (module) scope
  scope().attr("yes") = 1;
  scope().attr("no") = 0;

  // Change the current scope
  { // -- limit C++ scope of outer
    scope outer
      = class_<X>("X")
      .def("f", &X::f)
      ;

     // Define a class Y in the current scope, X
     class_<X::Y>("Y")
       .def("g", &X::Y::g)
       ;

  } // -- finish scope "outer" --

  // Start new scope
  scope outer2
    = class_<Z>("Z")
    .def("f", &Z::f)
    ;

  // Define a class Y in the current scope, X
   class_<Z::W>("W")
     .def("g", &Z::W::g)
     ;
}
```

There is a similar answer here: [boost::python nested namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765596/create-boost-python-nested-namespace)