# How to expose with swig C++ namespaces as python modules

Tags: python, c++, swig

Having C++ code:

```
namespace ns {
    struct Person {};
}
```

I would like to expose `Person` class to python in a module `ns`:

```
import libapp
x = libapp.ns.Person()
```

Is it possible using swig?

I other workds I would like to map `C++` namespace hierarchy to `Python` module hierarchy.

I have a wrapper written in `Boost.Python` (it allows such [mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17188326/2795046)) and I'm switching to swig, so I do not want to rewrite wrapper client code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest answer to this is to write one SWIG module per namespace that you want to expose, so in the instance above you'd write a SWIG module called `ns` inside your libapp package.

You can reference the other namespaces still within other modules using the SWIG `%import` directive.

You could also do some juggling with either the runtime information SWIG produces to hook this up at runtime, or even at compile time, but the complexity of doing so far outweighs the benefits of splitting your module up cleanly anyway.

Comment: How to nest modules in SWIG? Can you give an example, please.