# Error in boost-python nested namespace exporting code

Tags: python, boost-python

I am working on exporting two classes class zoo (extzoo and intzoo
namespaces), class animal (extanim and intanim namespaces)" methods which are
   defined within two level nested namespaces. I want to expose these methods
 to   Python interpreter from where I can access them. I have written code, 
created a   shared library but when I import it into a python I get an error. 
I will appreciate your guidance on this.

I have followed the answer given on the following link in similar context
 of exposing C++ nested namespaces: [create boost-python nested namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765596/create-boost-python-nested-namespace)

zoo.h:

```
namespace extzoo
{
namespace intzoo
{
class zoo
{
public:
const std::string hello_zoo();
const std::string getname_zoo();
};
}
}
```

zoo.cpp:

```
using namespace extzoo;
using namespace intzoo;

const std::string zoo::hello_zoo() {
     return std::string("hello, zoo");
}

const std::string zoo::getname_zoo() {
      std::string input;
      std::cout<<"Please enter your favorit zoo name: ";
      std::getline(std::cin,input);
      return std::string("Your favorit zoo name is: ").append(input);
}
```

animal.h:

```
namespace extanim
{
namespace intanim
{
class animal
{
public:
const std::string hello_animal();     
const std::string getname_animal();
};
}
}
```

animal.cpp:

```
using namespace extanim;
using namespace intanim;

const std::string animal::hello_animal() {
      return std::string("hello, animal");
}
const std::string animal::getname_animal() {
      std::string input;
      std::cout<<"Please enter your favorit animal name: ";
      std::getline(std::cin,input);
      return std::string("Your favorit animal name is: ").append(input);
     }
```

pyintf.cpp:

```
// An established convention for using boost.python.
using namespace boost::python;
//user defined ns
using namespace extzoo::intzoo;
using namespace extzoo;
using namespace extanim::intanim;
using namespace extanim;

class DummyZoo{};
class DummyAnimal{};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(pyintf) {

    scope intzoo
    = class_<DummyZoo>("intzoo");

    class_<extzoo::intzoo::zoo>("zoo")
    // Expose the function hello_zoo().
       .def("hello_zoo", &extzoo::intzoo::zoo::hello_zoo)
        // Expose the function getname_zoo().    
        .def("getname_zoo", &extzoo::intzoo::zoo::getname_zoo)
        ;



    scope intanim
        = class_<DummyAnimal>("intanim"); 

    class_<extanim::intanim::animal>("animal")
        // Expose the function hello_animal().
        .def("hello_animal", &extanim::intanim::animal::hello_animal)
        // Expose the function getname_animal().    
        .def("getname_animal", &extanim::intanim::animal::getname_animal)
        ;
}
```

I have compiled the above code using following command:

```
g++ -shared -o pyintf.so -fPIC pyintf.cpp zoo.h zoo.cpp animal.h animal.cpp -lboost_python -lpython2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7
```

I am getting error on importing the shared library

> > > import pyintf
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >       File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ImportError: ./pyintf.so: undefined symbol: _ZN7extanim7intanim6animal14getname_animalEv

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++Update+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

I have changed the code based on @doqtor suggestion. However, now I cannot import in Python a namespace 'intanim' defined in one file while other can 'intzoo'. As you may see below.

```
>>> import pyintf 
>>> pyintf.intanim.animal().hello_animal()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'intanim'
>>> from pyintf import intanim
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name intanim
>>> from pyintf import extanim
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name extanim
>>> from pyintf import intzoo
>>> intzoo.zoo().hello_zoo()
'hello, zoo'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your cpp files you need to put definitions of the class methods inside the appropriate namespaces instead of `using namespace ...` declarations. For example for zoo.cpp that will be:

```
namespace extzoo
{
namespace intzoo
{
const std::string zoo::hello_zoo() {
// ... code
}

const std::string zoo::getname_zoo() {
// ... code
}
}
}
```

--------------------------------------------- **Update** ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Add scope in c++ code to separate definitions of python scope using `{}`:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(pyintf) { // set scope to pyintf

{
    scope intzoo
    = class_<DummyZoo>("intzoo"); // define and set scope to pyintf.intzoo

    class_<extzoo::intzoo::zoo>("zoo")
    // Expose the function hello_zoo().
       .def("hello_zoo", &extzoo::intzoo::zoo::hello_zoo)
        // Expose the function getname_zoo().    
        .def("getname_zoo", &extzoo::intzoo::zoo::getname_zoo)
        ;
} // revert scope to pyintf


{
    scope intanim
        = class_<DummyAnimal>("intanim"); // define and set scope to pyintf.intanim

    class_<extanim::intanim::animal>("animal")
        // Expose the function hello_animal().
        .def("hello_animal", &extanim::intanim::animal::hello_animal)
        // Expose the function getname_animal().    
        .def("getname_animal", &extanim::intanim::animal::getname_animal)
        ;
} // revert scope to pyintf

}
```

And the test:

```
>>> import pyintf
>>> dir(pyintf)
['__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'intanim', 'intzoo']
>>> pyintf.intanim.animal().hello_animal()
'hello, animal'
>>> from pyintf import intanim
>>> from pyintf import extanim
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name extanim
>>> from pyintf import intzoo
>>>
```

Note that error on importing `extanim` is expected as there isn't scope of such name defined.

Comment: I have updated the code as per your suggestion. However, I can import intzoo but cannot import intanim namespace. I have pasted the error.

Comment: @EjazAhmed the content of the question shouldn't be modified, now what I put in my answer doesn't make sense as your question already contain that. Also publish updates rather at the bottom than at the top of the question.

Comment: changed accordingly. Do you have any idea on new error I have pasted above?